# Missing extention for php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to install word-press on my website. i have php and its working and my mysql is working too. i need to install mysql extension for php.

This is my error im getting when trying the word-press install file.

"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

thanks

btw its windows using IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't mention what OS you're using. just the same, here's a link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-mysql-php-support-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

Google (and StackOverflow's sister site) to the (potential) rescue! :)

https://superuser.com/questions/58470/wordpress-problem-your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-extensio

Answer (score 0):

What is the path to php_mysql.dll? Is it correct in php.ini?

If you don't have access to php.ini, talk to your web host.

Comment: i have access. what mapping do i use c:/... or just theb filename??